# Variadic C++ Templates Termination After Unpack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I'm trying to use C++ variadic templates to unpack a list of arguments of variable type, how would I remove the "T" object in the following artificial example:

```
struct Test
{
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void foo(T t, int i, Args... args) { foo(t, args...); }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void foo(T t, double d, Args... args) { foo(t, args...); }

    template <typename T>
    void foo(T t) { }
};

struct DummyObject { };
```

and then executed like this:

```
DummyObject dummy;
Test test;
test.foo(dummy, 4, 5.0, 6, 7.0, 8.0, 9);
```

I'd like to remove the need to pass in the "dummy" object at all, I just can't figure out what the final "foo" function should look like in this case.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what you do with `i` and `d` parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me flesh out your sample slightly:

```
struct Test
{
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void foo(T t, int i, Args... args) { doIThing(i); foo(t, args...); }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void foo(T t, double d, Args... args) { doDThing(d);  foo(t, args...); }

    template <typename T>
    void foo(T t) { }
};
```

So there's the two functions that do actual work: `doIThing` and `doDThing`. You got it 99% right, just... remove T.

```
struct Test
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void foo(int i, Args... args) { doIThing(i); foo(args...); }

    template <typename... Args>
    void foo(double d, Args... args) { doDThing(d);  foo(args...); }

    void foo() { }
};
```

Running here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b35ac716cf2960b3

Answer (score 2):

Other method is to remove recursive call and have something like:

```
struct Test
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void foos(Args... args)
    {
        (foo(args), ...); // C++17 fold expression
#if 0 // C++11 or C++14
        const int dummy[] = {0, (foo(args), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable
#endif
    }

    void foo(int t) { /*...*/ }

    void foo(double t) { /*...*/ }

    template <typename t> void foo(T t) { /**/ }

};
```

And then use it:

```
Test test;
test.foos(4, 5.0, 6, 7.0, 8.0, 9);
```